# conflict in promise code

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Consider this code. Suppose the `first catch` block gets executed then the problem is how you can determine whether it was caused by `testP` or the `first then` promise.

```
var testP = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //reject or resolve
    });
}

testP().then(function(res){
    console.log("first then");
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        // reject or resolve
    })
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log("first catch");
    console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

If you want to distinguish? you should use second argument of `then`.

```
testP().then(function(res){
    console.log("first then");
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        // reject or resolve
    })
}, function(err){
    console.log("first catch");
    console.log(err);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log("second catch");
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: couldn't the OP check the type of `err` ?

Comment: @niceman Yes, kinda he could, if promises were rejected with specific errors, e.g. `reject(new Error("TESTP_ERROR"))` and `reject(new Error("THEN_ERROR"))`, one could check `err.message` in their catch callback and act accordingly. Morever, if you prefer to go the route of defining your own errors extending `Error`, you could then check `if (err instanceof MyCustomError`. Beware that in general other runtime errors could happen in the code as well, e.g. calling a function on an undefined object, so one must take into account that those would invoke the `catch` callback as well.

Comment: Usually, the way you solve this is to just distinguish the type of error that you are catching.  Or, if you want to handle a specific error and then let the chain continue from there, you put a `.catch()` right after the `.then()` who's error you want to catch.